# SignalR Server Hosting

Tags: asp.net, signalr

We've been trying to implement SignalR for a browser MMO, and so far it works great. We managed to separate client from server, and even have them on separate computers. The thing is, this works when both computers are on the same network. We just change the IP to which it the client points to, and it works like a charm.

Now, the issue arises when the host is on another network. Namely, our server is an Amazon Web Service virtual machine, but we've even tied hosting ourselves on other IPs. We can't seem to find a way to point to the local address within the public address. By pointing to a global IP, we're only pointing to a router, but we want to be able to access a computer within that address.

How do we get around to doing this? Can we specify global address AND local address? Do we need to configure a forwarding rule?

Comment: It seems that you need to study some computer networking. If you host the SignalR server on an AWS instance, it should bind to the private IP of that instance. The clients should attempt to connect to the public IP and the routing is done by AWS.

Comment: Thank you! Apparently there was a somewhat obscure option within the EC2 management panel to manage inbound rules. Once that was changed, it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the very specific case of AWS, there's a somewhat obscure option for inbound rules. Once logged on the AWS homepage, you'll be taken to the management console. Then, choose "EC2 - Virtual Servers in the Cloud", and click on "Security Groups". If you don't have any security groups created,  you'll need to create one - there's a detailed tutorial for that on that same screen. Choose a group, and then click on the Actions icon (right next to the "Create Security Group" button), and from the drop-down menu, select "edit inbound rules". You then have click "Add Rule", choose a "Custom TCP rule", select the port on which the rule to be created, and any source IPs that apply to this rule (usually "anywhere" is the desired option). Finally, hit the save button, and this rule should be in effect immediately.

Hope this helps someone!